# How to make ONE cell ReadOnly?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Not the whole row, not the whole column, just one cell. The `DataGridView` ReadOnly property is set to false (default). If the condition is met at the row level, allow specific cells to be ReadOnly false/true

```cs
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgv.Rows)
{
    if (!Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells["Cell 0"].Value))
    {
        row.Cells["Cell 3"].ReadOnly = false;  // The Cell 3 for the current row (only this row, only this cell)
                                               // is set to ReadOnly = false
    }
    else
    {
        row.Cells["Cell 3"].ReadOnly = true;  // The Cell 3 for the current row (only this row, only this cell)
                                              // is set to ReadOnly = true
    }
}
```

Comment: Set & `break;` the loop? Are you using the real column names? You are showing invalid identifiers here.

Answer (score 1):

The identifiers you're providing in `row.Cells[]` is incorrect. You should be providing the column name there and not cell names!

Example:

```cs
dataGridView1.Rows.Add("test", "false");
dataGridView1.Rows.Add("sfsdf", "true");
dataGridView1.Rows.Add("hjdfg", "false");

foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    // Will check the value of the cell in current row and column "Column2"
    if (Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells["Column2"].Value))
        row.Cells["Column2"].ReadOnly = true; // Sets the property of that cell
}
```

If you want you can shorten that code to set the `readonly` property all cells in a specific column to the specific cell value:

```cs
row.Cells["Column2"].ReadOnly = Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells["Column2"].Value);
```

Comment: @dr.null Very good! Updated the answer